# The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, maven

While trying to compile some project from GitHub, I met the following error

```
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

If I am not mistaking, this is the class from basic JDK. How can it be unreacheable?

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: run a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Are you compiling for Java ME?

Comment: I see this error when I clone maven projects into my eclipse with m2e. Have you tried "Maven->Update Project" from the context of the prject node?

Comment: `CharSequence` was added in Java 1.4. Do you have a _really_ old copy of java on your computer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Doing the "Maven->Update Project" from the context of the project node (AKA Alt-F5) as suggested by the comment from @hajo-thelen above does this trick and resolves this problem.