# I have deployed my WAR in JBOSS environment but on login i`m getting this error

Tags: java, jboss

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 407 in the jsp file: /jsp/administration/MainMenuHorizontal.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
404:
405:                     //This is for displaying the footer data
406:                     //strFooterData.append("").append(objMenu.getMenuName());
407:                     strFooterData.append("").append(objMenu.getMenuName());
408:                     /*
409:                      * First adding to an arraylist coz fist the TD needs to be equally distributed 
410:                      * so cant know the number in the begining itself

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR2 logs.

Comment: Which version of java is used to run JBoss ?

Comment: I`m using JDK 1.6

Comment: see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167357/how-to-fix-the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectl)