# I want to copy data in a 2-D array into an excel sheet with Java

Tags: java

The below is my code and I am facing (The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files) error which will occur for `myCell.setCellValue(value);` statement.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class test3 {
    private static String dest = "D:\\testexcel.xls";
    private static HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    private static HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet();

    private static void excelLog(int row, int col, String value) {
        HSSFRow myRow = mySheet.getRow(row);

        if (myRow == null)
            myRow = mySheet.createRow(row);

        HSSFCell myCell = myRow.createCell(col);
        myCell.setCellValue(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numCol = 10; // assume 10 cols

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
                excelLog(i, j, "Row : " + i + ", Cell : " + j);
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            myWorkBook.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This ran without errors on my macbook pro jdk 8 my gradle entry is compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'

Comment: appaci poi 3.17

Comment: I tried 3.17 with no change(as in still working for me) what version of java are you on

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I am using Windows(10)

Comment: Can you put a `System.out.println(value)`above the line with the error and edit the results into your initial post?

Comment: What version of java are you on?

Comment: @Matt looking it up it's in the base module so it shouldn't be an issue with java9+

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is just an IDE build process related issue, code works perfect for *org.apache.poi* version *3.17*.

1. Please try to clean the project and build it once again.
2. If it will not work delete the project from your IDE and import it once again - this should help.

As a quick check for this (in case of using build tool) - you can run build process from `cmd` and it should work.

Comment: There is something similar [here >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167357/how-to-fix-the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectl)