# Getting Exception with SendKeys Method in Java Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am getting exception while trying to implement sendKeys as "The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files". I am trying to type a  number 300 in a textbox with id "min-value". This is a java code to run in selenium.

I have jre 8 installed on my system.

Below is the code which gives problem

`driver.findElement(By.id("min-value")).sendKeys("300");`

I have imported all the required Selenium webdriver packages. I am working on Eclipse 3.3 version

Can anyone please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Comment: Vinoth - Can you please elaborate a bit. What is the solution?

Comment: In Project Settings, Java Build Path/Libraries tab make sure you have JRE 1.7 & try

Comment: Or use latest eclipse

Comment: It worked.. JRE 1.7 is working for sendKeys. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

JRE 1.7 supports the methods. This is working with 1.7

Just need to change the JAR to 1.7 in Project > Properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JRE 1.7 which support that method.

you will check your installed JRE from following path in Eclipse

```
Menu-->Preferences-->java-->Installed JREs
```

and you can add new jars of JRE 1.7 from following path in Eclipse

```
Right click on Project-->Build Path-->Configure Build Path-->Java Build path-->Libraries-->Add jar files
```