# string.startsWithIgnoreCase("") returns error?

Tags: java, ignore-case

When I type in the following code into Eclipse:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Please input a word ");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();

if(input.startsWithIgnoreCase("pre"))
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return "blah";
    }
```

It red-underlines the **input.startsWithIgnoreCase("pre")** part and returns the following error: "The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

I'm not sure why it returns this error or what it even means. What I want to do is check that the inputted word starts with "pre" while ignoring case.

Comment: What Java version are you targeting in the project settings?

Comment: what is the "input" variable ? ,

Comment: [This should help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's an actual method that comes in the `String` class (correct me if I'm wrong). You would have to do something like this instead: `input.toLowerCase().startsWith(string.toLowerCase())`
In your case `string` would be "pre"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(input.toLowerCase().startsWith("pre"))
```