# I am trying to run a jsp project in tomcat 6.0. But I am getting the following error

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

An error occurred at line: 152 in the jsp file: /user.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
 149:       int length=5;
    150:         for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++ ) {  
    151:             int pos = rand.nextInt(charset1.length()); 
    152:             sb.append(charset1.charAt(pos));  
    153:         }
```

Stacktrace:

```
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
       org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:423)
                    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
                    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
                   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
      org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
                org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
                     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.14 logs.
```

Comment: what is the version of your JDK?

Comment: are you using java 8?

Comment: yes , am using JDK 8
 and while tomcat installation , it auto searched for JRE
c:\program files (X86)\java\jre6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Answer (score 0):

> Java 8 supports default methods in interfaces. And in JDK 8 a lot of
>   old interfaces now have new default methods. For example, now in
>   CharSequence we have chars and codePoints methods. If source level of
>   your project is lower than 1.8, then compiler doesn't allow you to use
>   default methods in interfaces. So it cannot compile classes that
>   directly on indirectly depend on this interfaces. If I get your
>   problem right, then you have two solutions. First solution is to
>   rollback to JDK 7, then you will use old CharSequence interface
>   without default methods. Second solution is to set source level of
>   your project to 1.8, then your compiler will not complain about
>   default methods in interfaces.

Ref : [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Comment: Now I used JDK 7, even it is showing the same error.
Do I need to reinstall tomcat?

Comment: I have changed the JAVA_HOME system variable path to  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0 
Even it is showing the same error

Comment: What is the source level in eclipse ? 1.8 ?

Comment: I didn't get you. But I am not using Eclipse