# Issues while upgrading to JDK1.8 Upgrade

Tags: java, weblogic

We are facing following issue at runtime **(WEBLOGIC 12.xxx) with jdk1.8**

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

The above issue is been thrown at runtime in a jsp.
We need to fix this issue in our unix server.  I see many posts giving suggestions to fix the issue in eclipse. I couldn't found any solution to fix this in unix machine.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration

Comment: hi Soorapadman, i did check the link and we are able to compile the code succesfully with jdk1.8. The issue we were thrown is from jsp at runtime.  can you help me in understanding "set source level of your project to 1.8"?

Comment: Windows>Preferences>Java>Compiler>compiler compliance level

Comment: but how can we do that in UNIX machine?

Comment: sorry bro i didn't  know about unix.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or some other IDE? Or are you compiling from the command line?

Comment: we are compiling from command line in UNIX. compilation gets successful. But during jsp compilation at runtime we are facing the issue. We are using weblogic 12.1.1.0.

Comment: It seems issue is with the version of weblogic we are using. "**Java 8 is supported on WebLogic Server 12.1.3. It is not supported on 10.3.6, 12.1.1, or 12.1.2.**"