# The type java.lang.Charsequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean"
 prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html"
 prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-logic"
 prefix="logic"%>
<%@ page import="de.fhg.fokus.hss.db.model.*, java.util.* " %>

<jsp:useBean id="resultList" type="java.util.List" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="maxPages" type="java.lang.String" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="currentPage" type="java.lang.String" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="rowPerPage" type="java.lang.String" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/hss.web.console/style/fokus_ngni.css">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><bean:message key="result.title" /></title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function submitForm(pageId){
 document.IMSU_SearchForm.crtPage.value = pageId;
 document.IMSU_SearchForm.submit();
}

function rowsPerPageChanged(){
 document.IMSU_SearchForm.crtPage.value = 1;
 document.IMSU_SearchForm.submit();
}

</script> 

</head>
<body>
 <table id="title-table" align="center" weight="100%" >
 <tr>
  <td align="center">
   <h1> IMS Subscription - Search Results </h1> 
   <br/><br/>  
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table> <!-- title-table -->

 <table id="main-table" align="center" valign="middle" >
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table id="result-table" class="as"  width="600" border="0" cellspacing="1" align="center" style="border:2px solid #FF6600;"> 
   <tr class="header">
    <td class="header"> ID </td>
    <td class="header"> Name </td>
    <td class="header"> S-CSCF Name </td>
    <td class="header"> Diameter Name </td>
   </tr>
   
   <%
    if (resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0){
     IMSU imsu;
     int idx = 0;
     Iterator it = resultList.iterator();
     
     while (it.hasNext()){
      imsu = (IMSU) it.next();
   %>   
   
      <tr class="<%= idx % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" %>">
       <td>
        <%= imsu.getId() %>
       </td>
       <td> 
        <a href="/hss.web.console/IMSU_Load.do?id=<%= imsu.getId() %>"> 
         <%= imsu.getName() %>
        </a> 
       </td>
       <td>
        <%= imsu.getScscf_name() %>
       </td>
       <td>
        <%= imsu.getDiameter_name() %>
       </td>
      </tr>
    <%  
      idx++;  
     } //while
    } // if
    else{ 
    %>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <bean:message key="result.emptyResultSet" />
      </td>
     </tr>      
    <%
    }
    %> 
     
   </table> <!-- result-table -->
  </td>
 </tr>      
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="header">
   <html:form action="/IMSU_Search">
   <table id="rows-table" align="center">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <%
      int length = Integer.parseInt(maxPages) + 1;
      int cPage = Integer.parseInt(currentPage) + 1;
      for (int iy = 1; iy < length; iy++) {
       if (cPage != iy) {
     %>
        <a href="javascript:submitForm(<%=String.valueOf(iy)%>);"><%=iy%></a>
     <%
       } else {
     %> 
         <font style="color:#FF0000;font-weight: 600;"> 
          <%=String.valueOf(iy)%>
         </font> 
     <%   }
      }
     %>
    </td>
    <td>
     <bean:message key="result.rowsPerPage" /><br>
     <html:hidden property="crtPage"></html:hidden> 
     <html:select property="rowsPerPage" onchange="javascript:rowsPerPageChanged();">
      <option value="20"
       <%= rowPerPage.equals("20") ? "selected" : "" %> >20 </option>
      <option value="30"
       <%= rowPerPage.equals("30") ? "selected" : "" %> >30 </option>
      <option value="50"
       <%= rowPerPage.equals("50") ? "selected" : "" %> >50</option>
      <option value="100"
       <%= rowPerPage.equals("100") ? "selected" : "" %> >100</option>
     </html:select>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </table> <!-- rows-table -->
   </html:form>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table> <!-- main-table -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to run a appliaction, I am accessing the application through a web interface but at some part I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: 116 in the jsp file: /pages/user/imsu_search_result.jsp
Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files


    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:84)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:397)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:288)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:267)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:556)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:293)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:291)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:241)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.9 logs.
```

Please find the attached jsp file
Please provide your suggestion to resolve the issue.
Thanks

Comment: show us the line number 116 of imsu_search_result.jsp

Comment: can you add your file imsu_search_result.jsp code?

Comment: java.lang.CharSequence is a java library. What version of Java is being used ? and who is the vendor ?

Comment: Are you using Java 8 by any chance for the tomcat ?

Comment: The line number 116 of imsu_search_result.jsp is
<a href="javascript:submitForm(<%=String.valueOf(iy)%>);"><%=iy%></a>

Comment: Please find the attached  imsu_search_result.jsp file above

Comment: yes I am using Java 1.8.0_25

Comment: Using java 8 could cause this problem. As found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration.

Comment: I tried with jdk1.7 to getting some Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Below is the detail trace of error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/fhg/fokus/hss/main/HSSContainer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your compiler and JVM versions as I believe they mismatch OR
2) Compile your all classes with newer version of 1.8 or 
3) downgrade to Java 1.7

Comment: @AmitKumar did you followed instructions of my answer and if my answer helped then please don't forget to mark it and vote up