# How to hide while fields are empty in i-report

Tags: jasper-reports

I wanted to hide text fields in jasper i-report when they are empty.

So I put this expression in those field's **Print When Expression**

```
$F{field_cashPaymentReceiptMode} != null && !"".equals($F{field_cashPaymentReceiptMode})
```

But then I got an error while compiling the report.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
                value = ((java.lang.String)field_cashPaymentReceiptMode.getValue())!=null &&!"".equals(((java.lang.String)field_cashPaymentReceiptMode.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=33$
                                                                                             <-------------------------------------------------------------------->
1 errors
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eliminate the **Print When Expression** altogether.
2. Check **Blank When NULL**.

[image: Blank When Null]

3. Optionally, check **Remove Line When Blank** (only use this if you want the field to disappear completely, rather than retain its space on the page but have no content).

[image: Remove Line When Blank]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order:

```
... && !$F{field_cashPaymentReceiptMode}.equals("")
```

If that doesn't help:

This could also depend on your JDK (1.7 / 1.8) version [as seen in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration). When using 1.8, try downgrading to 1.7 if possible. This happens because of new default methods in interfaces in 1.8.