# Android Studio / App Engine Dev Server version incompatibility (Java 7 vs 8)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, jetty

I'm trying to develop a project using Android Studio which includes an App Engine component.

- App Engine only supports compiling with Java 7 (will not allow me to deploy the app if compiled with Java 8: "Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7").
- The latest versions of Android Studio only support JDK 8 (will not let me select a Java 7 JDK in project options: "Please choose JDK 8 or newer").

The best workaround I can find is to specify options to compile with Java 7 compatibility via Gradle config files:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

This allows me to develop using Android Studio, using JDK 8, and deploy to App Engine. However, when I run the Jetty-based local/dev server, I run into the issue mentioned here: [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration).

It seems like targeting Java 7 using the Java 8 JDK may not be sufficient, and I will need to use a real v7 JDK in order to get around this issue?

Any solutions?