# When i updated Jdk 1.6 to Jdk 1.8, I get the following error : The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-6

I am getting  "**java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**" error, after updating the JDK version from 1.6 to jdk 1.8 and when i press ctrl+space in IDE it is not showing any proposed templates(not auto-populating any methods). I have changed the Installed JREs to point to 1.8 (windows->prefrences->java->Installed JREs),included JDK 1.8 in the buildpath, Java Compiler or Compliance level is still 1.6(windows->prefrences->java->Compiler), which is the max compilance level shows in my IDE.

What is causing  the issue? Can anyone help me how to resolve this problem?

IDE - Eclipse Galileo

DB - Oracle 11.2

JDK - 1.8

Compiler - 1.6

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Update the compiler?

Comment: I think you are doing development,So you should include JDK in your buildpath not JRE @yoganandh

Comment: @cricket_007 I have no clue how to update compiler. can you help me how to update the compiler?

Comment: @Darshit Ya I have included JDK only in my buildpath

Comment: Change compiler in window > preference > project facets. Change java version to 1.8 and restart workbench.

Comment: @Darshit As i alredy mentioned in my question my IDE shows compilance level only upto 1.6

Comment: Eclipse Galileo (3.5) is ancient, if you actually want to use the new Java 8 features such as lambda expressions you will have to move to a much newer release of Eclipse (Neon 4.6.2 is the current release).

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks! I'll try updating eclipse but Is there a way to solve this without upgrading eclipse? because the project was completly developed usuing 1.6  and we just need to check whether the application runs without errors.

Comment: No, there is no way around upgrading your IDE. The answer of the linked question explains why.

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility mode of JAVA compilations for previous versions, when you're using newer versions is not perfect, i had different issues with that in the past.
If you have a project compiled in 1.6 use JDK 1.6 instead of compatibility mode.
In eclipse is easy to configure different JDK for different projects.

Comment: I have already tried with 1.6 it is working. but now I am supposed to update JDK from 1.6 to 1.8 that is the task given for me. Can you give any solution for this problem?

Comment: I am using JDK only. I have updated in my question thanks.

Comment: Read these thread(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration) May be duplicated question. Resuming: "Java 8 supports default methods in interfaces. And in JDK 8 a lot of old interfaces now have new default methods. ...."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no reference to old JDK version in the eclipse.ini, and JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the latest version of JDK