# sendKeys(CharSequence[]) error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have installed java JDK1.8.0_05. I am using selenium 2.50.0. I have entered below code:

```
username.sendKeys("Ashok");
```

and I got the error  as below.

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class    files
>     - The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) from the type WebElement refers to the missing type    CharSequence

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: It will be great if you will provide your full tried code.

Comment: Upgrade your Selenium version to 3.0 or above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Comment: It would be nice if you spent a few minutes googling error messages, etc. and trying to find an answer to your question before asking it here. I googled the error message and the first result contains your answer.

Answer (score 0):

change your jre to 1.6 will be ok