# IBM Domino Java cannot be compiled due to charsequence error

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I got this problem:

[image]

At code:

```
DueDate = DueDate.replace("[", "");
```

And if I remove this code then it jumps to another piece of code with the same error. I tried much things, removing database from designer and workspace, cache.ndk, removing the workspace folder from data folder, removing bookmarks, readding jars, deleting java file and readding. Changing compiler compliance settings to 1.5 and to 1.6 But nothing works.

How can i fix this, because it always worked.

Comment: what version (not compliancy) are you compiling/running with? you may want to check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration

Comment: IDE you are using?

Comment: `eclipse` / `domino-designer-eclipse`? And maybe also using `maven`?

Comment: domino designer with eclipse intergrated

Comment: Using `maven` or such?

Comment: No @pirho not using maven

Comment: Then i can only say that check that you really have JDK/JRE lib in your class path. I had once Maven Eclipse project which for some reason when updated REMOVED JDK/JRE  from classpath that is why asked that.Had to always add it back manually. Could not fix it and i had to create a new project from scratch and copy sources there. Try that if nothing else helps.