# RuleBaseLoader loadFromInputStream drools 2.5 compilation error on Java8 and weblogic12c

Tags: java-8, drools, weblogic12c, rule-engine

We are facing compilation error while compiling Rule Base from DB on server using drools-io-2.5.jar.

```
RuleBaseLoader.loadFromInputStream(stream);
```

stream is XML input stream picked from database.

This code is working with JAVA6 and weblogic 11g but we start getting error when we deployed on weblogic 12c on JAVA8.

Can someone please give a direction, how to resolve this.

Error:

```
<09-09-2020 18:12:47.235> <DEBUG> <ejbframework> <system> <RulesHelper> <subscriber-type-rules Checking rule base: subscribertypemapping>
<09-09-2020 18:12:47.237> <DEBUG> <ejbframework> <system> <RulesHelper> <subscriber-type-rules (Re)loading rule base: subscribertypemapping>
<09-09-2020 18:12:47.237> <DEBUG> <ejbframework> <system> <RulesHelper> <subscriber-type-rules Loading subscribertypemapping rulebase>
<09-09-2020 18:12:48.301> <DEBUG> <ejbframework> <system> <RulesHelper> <subscriber-type-rules Unexpected Error: A problem occured compiling the embedded code:
drools/org/subscribertypemapping_1599664368295/java/Function_0_0.java(28)
The type java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
<09-09-2020 18:12:48.301> <DEBUG> <ejbframework> <system> <RulesHelper> <subscriber-type-rules Problem with loading Rulebase: subscribertypemapping>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you post the compilation error message ?

Comment: updated the question with error, thanks

Comment: Seems like an issue similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration

Comment: Yeah, I agree with trim24 -- you're dealing with a version of this library which is just shy of 15 years old. Java has changed sufficiently that it's likely you're running into a language feature that it's using that no longer exists or is supported (or which isn't sufficiently backwards compatible.)