# Does drools-6.5 has backward compatibility of drools-2.5?

Tags: java-8, drools, weblogic12c, rule-engine, business-rules

We are using drools-decisiontables-2.1.jar to generate XMLs from Rulesheets(.XLS file). And, using drools-core-2.5 version to read those XMLs.

Now, we are upgrading from weblogic11g/Java6 to weblogic12c/Java8 and drools-2.5 is failing.
**JARs used in our project:** drools-base-2.5.jar, drools-core-2.5.jar, drools-io-2.5.jar, drools-java-2.5.jar, drools-smf-2.5.jar

**Issue we are facing in our code:**
[RuleBaseLoader loadFromInputStream drools 2.5 compilation error on Java8 and weblogic12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858437/rulebaseloader-loadfrominputstream-drools-2-5-compilation-error-on-java8-and-web)

Does drools-6.5 JARs has backward compatibility of drools-2.x for XMLs so that we can easily upgrade to newer versions of drools ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Drools 2.5 is from 2005 as far as I can tell. It's likely time to update.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas 70% of the XML files are working fine. We are only getting error for below category:
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved
The type java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement cannot be resolved
The type java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap cannot be resolved
The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved

Comment: Fore more detail see my last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858437/rulebaseloader-loadfrominputstream-drools-2-5-compilation-error-on-java8-and-web
you answered on this question as well :)

Comment: Honestly you're not very likely to find very many (if anyone) who still uses this ancient version who will be able to speak authoritatively on the subject. Your best best is likely to just do the upgrade and try yourself. (as an example, I've been doing Drools for 10 years now, but the oldest I've ever used is 5.0.)

Comment: Agree. Need your small suggestion. I have updated rt.jar of JDK8 and replaced "AnnotatedElement.class", "CharSequence.class" from JDK7 in their respective paths and fortunately it started working my local machine. Is there any impact which you can think of ? Also, when I uploaded modified rt.jar on weblogic server, we are unable to start the server.
Thanks in advance.